# using QTkit for recording audio

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, qtkit

It looks like using core audio to record audio is overly complicated.  While QTkit is basic and down to earth However.  All of the examples I have see integrate video and audio together.  Does some one have or know an example of using QTkit for recording audio?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AudioDataOutputToAudioUnit/Listings/CaptureSessionController_m.html) is an example of using QTKit for recording audio.

Answer (score 1):

In order to capture audio only, you have to either select the default device that supports sounds, or disable video connection on muxed devices.

```
// Get the default sound capture device
QTCaptureDevice *theDefaultSoundDevice = [QTCaptureDevice defaultInputDeviceWithMediaType: QTMediaTypeSound];
```

To learn how to disable connection on muxed devices, see the [QTKit Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/UsingQTKit/UsingQTKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008156-CH108-SW38). The sample code in the guide shows how to disable audio, so you just have to disable video instead.

Comment: When I save the file, will it be an aac file?

Comment: As far as I know, the QTKit only capture audio and/or video to mov files (with the QTCaptureMovieFileOutput). The mov file can contains audio, video or both of them.