# How to record Audio and Video at Mac separately?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm building application that needs to send recorded audio and video data to net separately.
Currently I'm using QTKit to capture media but it only allows to work with video and audio data combined.
Is there any way or frameworks that allows to work with video and audio apart?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using QTkit for recording audio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937720/using-qtkit-for-recording-audio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using QTKit to capture media but it only allows to work with video
>   and audio data combined.

False.

You can add multiple inputs and outputs to your capture session with QTKit. They don't have to combine the A/V. [Start here and read the entire document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html), then post another question if you have trouble.

Answer (score 1):

AVFoundation framework also support for recording audio and video.
 refer this sample code

[AVRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AVRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011004)

but this framework only support for OS X v10.7 or later